# Is it possible to represent this transformation in a strongly typed manner?

Tags: haskell, types, f#

I'm looking to perform a transformation like (in F#):

```ml
type Test = TBool of bool | TString of string

type TestList = TLBool of bool list | TLString of string list

let transform : Map<int, Test> list -> Map<int, TestList> = ??
```

Is there a way to encode this such that we "know" that while the Map contains heterogeneous values, the value at each position is the same type across elements of the containing list? The Maps would be of static size once constructed and the same across each list element, but the size is not known in advance so I'm basically looking to generate tuples/records of an unknown size.

**Edit**

I think my example was unclear. The root of what I'm after is to be able to take two variable sized collections whose values at a given position are always the same type, but that the collection itself can contain values of multiple types, and "zip" them together using the knowledge that at a given position the two values are the same type. Specifically, I don't want to have to recheck that they are the same and propagate the condition that they vary (as an error of some sort), since I already do exactly that when initially creating the collections.

**Edit 2**

From a comment posted below: I do essentially want heterogenous lists (I used maps since my indices can be sparse, but I could always use lists with an index mapping), but with the additional constraint that two instances of the heterogenous list can be "zipped together" and the values at a given index are of the same type.

Comment: I think the thing you're looking for is dependent types.  F# doesn't have it.  You could probably achieve this using code generation.

Comment: Indeed dependent types did come to mind and I would assume this is something that could be handled in such a system, but I know that some things that require dependent types to be "nice" are still able to be encoded in less powerful type systems with additional effort. I'm just wondering which classification this problem falls in.

Comment: There is a tuple type for each size of tuple and records have a fixed size at compile-time.  This pretty much leaves meta programming of some sort being your only option. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx for the tuple types.

Comment: Hmm I actually do remember reading something a while ago where someone wanted to automatically generate functions for combining record instances. If the records themselves could also be generated perhaps that would work.

Comment: How is the initial list of maps populated?

Comment: My feeling is that you can not even statically express that a simpler `foo : Test -> TestList` maps bools into bool-lists and the int analogous. In Haskell we could use GADTs for enforcing this statically, at the cost of changing the `Test,TestList` types a bit. (And then the heterogeneous maps would need existential types.)

Comment: @Daniel It's a .csv that's combined with an interpreter that parses each field according to a specification. The parsing specification is defined at a column level, which is why I "know" that each index contains the same type of value (otherwise it would have failed during construction), I just don't know how to propagate that knowledge. I'm not tied to the list of maps representation at all (and actually don't think it's possible using those structures alone), it's just what is currently used.

Comment: @chi Yes I think you're right about the Test -> TestList encoding and I'm actually not concerned with that constraint. My goal is simply to avoid "rechecking" and having to re-propagate error conditions that I "know" are impossible. If you're able to elaborate on a Haskell implementation I actually have more experience with Haskell than F# and I know there are ways of expressing [some?] existentials in F# with additional effort.

Comment: @ZJM Could explain more of what you want to do with the data? Maybe heterogeneous lists are tangential.

Comment: @Daniel Sure. I agree perhaps I'm approaching things incorrectly. So I have tabular data (delimited text, SQL result, etc.) and an expression language (number/date arithmetic and boolean logic, for now) allowing virtual fields that is evaluated within the context of a parsed record. All of this works fine (though some parts aren't pretty). But now I need to represent a "group by" operation on this data so that each group (list of records) is transformed into a record of lists and passed to the aggregation component of the specification.

Comment: Is the parsing specification (the types of columns) defined at compile time or at run time? And how is the specification given?

Comment: @PetrPudlák It is at run time and user defined. The specification is in the form of a simple expression language with variables being fields in the context of a record (raw values or virtual fields). There is something of a type checking pass prior to the grouping transformation which is why I "know" earlier that all the values in a given field are of the same type. Currently the specification is stored in a database.

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit** [...] The root of what I'm after is to be able to take two variable sized collections whose values at a given position are always the same type, but that the collection itself can contain values of multiple types, and "zip" them together using the knowledge that at a given position the two values are the same type.

This, in its broadest reading, fundamentally requires that the types of the collections encode which position contains which element type, and this dips into dependent types territory.

If there is one fixed shape of collection that can be determined at compilation time, however, then it's easy—you just write a type all of whose values have that shape.

Comment: I have not worked with dependent types as my understanding is that current implementations are not yet practical for general usage. Are there any more specific terms that I could perhaps investigate in order to determine whether this particular application has a representation in less powerful systems? Unfortunately I cannot know at compile time since the positions are dependent on user input, and they would be too large to, for example, generate all permutations (current instances are ~50 fields and will be much larger).

Comment: @ZJM: that sounds more like structural record types than collections.  But I'm afraid that structural record types are another thing that barely any mature languages have support for; you might want to look at O'Caml's object system for one of the better examples.  It still might not be enough, because if the field names and types aren't known at compilation time, it's also a matter of runtime reflection into structural record types.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `transformMap` function that has the property you want (i.e. preserves the key and turns strings to lists of strings and bools to lists of bools). The function can still be fully parametric in what it does with the values:

```ml
let transformMap fstr fbool map = 
  map |> Map.map (fun k v -> 
    match v with 
    | TBool b -> TLBool(fbool k b)
    | TString s -> TLString(fstr k s) )
```

Any transformation that you then perform on your map using `transformMap` has the properties you want. If you wanted to be more strict, you could write a wrapper over `Map<'K, TestList>` and hide the internal representation, which would give you a strong guarantee. In practice, I think it is probably reasonable to make the internals public, but check by hand that you only manipulate the map using your correct transformation function.

An example that turns each value into a singleton list using this function looks like this:

```ml
Map.empty |> transformMap
  (fun k s -> [s])
  (fun k b -> [b])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This isn't quite what I'm looking for, though. I'm actually trying to "collapse" multiple Maps into a single Map, with the values being lists of the values in the component maps. The piece I want to avoid is having to check whether the values from two maps are of the same type and propagating that exception, since I do that check at construction time so I "know", but just don't know how to encode that knowledge in the type system.

Comment: @ZJM You should add that to the question.

Comment: @chi Thanks I updated the question to try to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do with `Test list` instead of `TestList`, the conversion is fairly straightforward:

```fs
let transform listOfMaps : Map<int, Test list> =
    listOfMaps
    |> Seq.collect Map.toSeq 
    |> Seq.groupBy fst
    |> Seq.map (fun (i, s) -> 
        let xs = s |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList
        i, xs)
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

As far as capturing your assumptions in the types, I suspect it's either impossible or much more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately this solution doesn't gain me anything since it just defers the "checking" of the types of the elements in the list until I process that list. I also suspect it may not be possible due to limitations of the type system, but would be happy with any solution no matter how convoluted - I do feel it would be worth the effort.

Comment: What do you mean by "checking of the types"? We do know that list elements are of the same type (as in `System.Type`). I thought you were trying to capture the fact that the keys of the resulting map are unique, prior to building the map.

Comment: I'm sorry I may have phrased my question unintuitively. My goal is to be able to collapse two maps (or more, but once I can do two I can recurse) "knowing" that though each map's value are heterogenous, the type of the value at a given key is the same between the two maps. I "know" this because that invariant is enforced at the time the map is constructed, but I currently lose that information from the perspective of the type system since I don't know how to encode it.

Comment: The types of the values of _all_ the keys are the same, right? `Map<'K, 'V>` means a map where all keys are of type `'K` and all values are of types `'V`. Maybe I still don't understand what you're saying...?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry. So the Test type allows my to combine bools and strings into a single type to use in a type constructor such as Map. However, I "know" that index 0 is always a TBool, index 1 is always a TString, etc. I would like to encode that information such that I can combine the maps [(0, TBool true); (1, TString "")] and [(0, TBool false); (1, TString "")] into [(0, TLBool [true;false]); (1, TLString ["", ""])] without having to check for (and propagate on error) the condition that the values at index 0 in the two maps are indeed both TBool.

Comment: @ZJM, do you just want heterogeneous lists? Not sure about F#, but in Haskell it's just `data HList as where HNil :: HList '[]; HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)`.

Comment: @user3237465 I do essentially want heterogenous lists (I used maps since my indices can be sparse, but I could always use lists with an index mapping), but with the additional constraint that two instances of the heterogenous list can be "zipped together" and the values at a given index are of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Heterogeneous lists with elements wrapped in some `f` are:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

infixr 5 :::

data HList f as where
    HNil  :: HList f '[]
    (:::) :: f a -> HList f as -> HList f (a ': as)
```

For example,

```
xs1 :: HList [] [Bool, Int]
xs1 = [True, False] ::: [1..3] ::: HNil

xs2 :: HList [] [Bool, Int]
xs2 = [True]        ::: [1..5] ::: HNil
```

It's easy to zip two `HList []`:

```
hzip :: HList [] as -> HList [] as -> HList [] as
hzip  HNil         HNil        = HNil
hzip (xs ::: xss) (ys ::: yss) = (xs ++ ys) ::: hzip xss yss
```

Or a bit more generally (and with the `Rank2Types` extension):

```
hzipWith :: (forall a. f a -> g a -> h a) -> HList f as -> HList g as -> HList h as
hzipWith f  HNil       HNil      = HNil
hzipWith f (x ::: xs) (y ::: ys) = f x y ::: hzipWith f xs ys

hzip :: HList [] as -> HList [] as -> HList [] as
hzip = hzipWith (++)
```

Then (requires `FlexibleInstances` and `FlexibleContexts`)

```
instance Show (HList f '[]) where
    show HNil = "HNil"

instance (Show (f a), Show (HList f as)) => Show (HList f (a ': as)) where
    show (x ::: xs) = show x ++ " ::: " ++ show xs 

main = print $ hzip xs1 xs2
```

prints `[True,False,True] ::: [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5] ::: HNil`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I do not fully understand and will need to play with it a bit. The hzipWith function appears to the form I'm looking for I'm just not sure the types line up the way I would need. But I do think I will learn something at least, and possibly be able to apply this to other problems!